# sed regex to Python re

Tags: python, regex, sed

Can anyone help me with translating this regex to Python `re` module?

`sed -e "s/^[^ ]* \([^ ]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9:]*\) \([0-9]*\) /\1 \2 \4 \3 /"`

As I've understood this replaces one text to another. How can I create something like this using `re` module? Thanks!

e.g. `Fri Mar 21 07:16:51 2008 -0600` will be converted to `Mar 21 2008 07:16:51 -0600`.

```
source = 'Fri Mar 21 07:16:51 2008 -0600'
pattern = re.compile('^[^ ]* \([^ ]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9:]*\) \([0-9]*\) ')
result = re.sub('\\1 \\2 \\4 \\3 ', source)
```

Comment: @nightcracker: I understand that I must use ``re.sub``, but I can't imagine what mean ``\1 \2 \4 \3``.

Comment: `\1 \2 \4 \3` can be matched using `\\1 \\2 \\4 \\3`, and aside from that, your regex *should* covert right over to Python's re module.

Comment: Can you include some sample inputs in your question?

Comment: I've added sample input and my try (thanks to @covertCoder). However it still doesn't work.

Comment: @NiklasB.: You don't think, but it works. ``data='Fri Mar 21 07:16:51 2008 -0600'; echo $data | sed -e "s/^[^ ]* \([^ ]*\) \([0-9]*\) \([0-9:]*\) \([0-9]*\) /\1 \2 \4 \3 /"``.

Comment: @ghostmansd: disregard my comment :)

Comment: That should probably also be `result = pattern.sub(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the backslashes on the parens in your pattern too, as in:

```
pattern = re.compile('^[^ ]* ([^ ]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9:]*) ([0-9]*) ')
```

The way you had it, you were escaping the parens which need to be recognized as groupings so that you actually capture the four groups corresponding to the \1 ... \4

Comment: Yeah, that works! But why? I need to screen these symbols only in ``sed``?

Comment: I'm not sure why it works in `sed`, but in python you escape special characters only when you want to match them, not use them as regex special characters :P. This is the cleanest answer you could probably get, which is why I deleted mine.

Comment: The backslashes in the sed command are escaping it for the command processor (bash/sh/whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the one-liner version:

```
import re
re.sub(r'^[^ ]* ([^ ]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9:]*) ([0-9]*) ', '\g<1> \g<2> \g<3> \g<4>', source)
```

Or this, using a compiled pattern - more efficient if the same regular expression is to be reused:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^[^ ]* ([^ ]*) ([0-9]*) ([0-9:]*) ([0-9]*) ')
pattern.sub('\g<1> \g<2> \g<3> \g<4>', source)
```

Comment: As I've understood there is no difference to use ``'\g<1>'`` or ``'\1'``?

Comment: `\g<1>` is a bit more general, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) you can use this syntax for referencing groups not only by number, but by name too. And it can be useful for avoiding certain ambiguities. Personally, I prefer this form.

Comment: Also, notice that it's a good idea to enclose regular expressions in `r''` (raw strings), in that way you avoid the need to escape special characters like "\"